# quicker way to develop a new processor and debug

Tags: open-telemetry

We want to develop a new adapted tail-based sampling **processor** in `opentelemetry-collector-contrib`.

Now we change the code in `opentelemetry-collector-contrib/processor/tailsamplingprocessor` and then use the tools in `opentelemetry-collector-releases` to build a new **collector image**, finally deploy it in k8s to checkout its correctness.

Is there a quicker way for us to develop and debug? What should we do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Golang standard: run&create Golang unit tests for your case(s). There are already some tests (see *_test.go files) https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/tailsamplingprocessor